# Give room owners the ability to edit their own old chat messages

Tags: feature-request, edits, chat

It seems strange to me that a diamond on any site (not just chat rooms for their site) can edit the old messages of *anyone* in *any chat room*, yet **room owners** can't edit their old messages in rooms they own after the expiration period.

Currently, Programmers.SE is in the middle of a tag cleanup and I've been updating a status message pin in the main chat room as progress is made on it. It would be a lot easier for me if I could just update the old pin instead of having [to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21800127#21800127) [make](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21828864#21828864) [a](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21862018#21862018) [fresh](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21862390#21862390) [pin](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21906318#21906318) [each](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21942111#21942111) [time.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=21970541#21970541)

Please give **room owners** the ability to edit their own old messages.

Comment: Yes, please. Room owners should have privileges similar to mods, in this sense.

Comment: Rene and I would be super happy to have this feature. Having to constantly make new messages and re-pin is a chore.

Comment: @HDE226868 I'm actually not asking for the ability to edit other people's messages like diamonds have, just their own.

Comment: @durron597 I know that, don't worry.

Comment: Never noticed this FR and didn't know I would be super happy if implemented...

Comment: You are asking for much greater privileges than needed to just change the pin (isn't it userscriptable?) A room owner may be deleting/nulling his/her messages, and this would leave chat/transcript readers bewildered and confused.

Comment: @DeerHunter They're a room owner, it's their room.

Comment: Should they have the ability to alter the past?

Comment: @DeerHunter Yes, it's their room. They are a room owner.

Comment: @durron597 not really "their room" as it implies they created it, while it's not always true. More like they are the room local moderators. Room can have unlimited amount of owners.